# Linear regression model of scikit-learn not working as expected

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm trying to understand the internal working of the Linear-regression model in Scikit-learn.

This is my dataset

[image: before 1 hot encoding]

And this is my dataset after performing one-hot-encoding.

[image: after 1 hot encoding]

And this are values of the coefficients and intercept after performing linear-regression.
[image: coefficients]

**Sell Price** is the dependent column and rest of the columns are features.
And these are the predicted values which works fine in this case.
[image: predicted values]

I noticed that the number of coefficients is 1 greater than the number of features. So this is how I generated the feature matrix:

```
feature_matrix = dataFrame.drop(['Sell Price($)'], axis = 'columns').to_numpy()

# Array to be added as column
bias_column = np.array([[1] for i in range(len(feature_matrix))])

# Adding column to array using append() method
feature_matrix = np.concatenate([bias_column, feature_matrix], axis = 1)  # axis = 1 means column, 0 means row
```

**Result**
[image]

What I want to know is how does Scikit-learn use these coefficients and intercept to predict the values.
This is what I tried.
[image]
I also noticed that the value I get by doing this calculation is actually equal to the mileage in every case. But that's not the dependent feature here. So what's going on?

Comment: 1. Please only share code and data as text, not images. 2. By the way, you could have done `bias = np.ones((len(feature_matrix),1))`.

Comment: It seems like you did not drop sell price from the training features just looking at your provided coefficients. the second one is 1 and the others are tiny and sell price is your send column from the shown screen caps so it is highly likely you setup your training incorrectly.

Comment: @KaranShishoo This is exactly the issue I was facing. Thank you

Comment: The question posed in the title is much broader than the specific problem you needed to solve. Please try to make sure your question titles reflect the actual question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get the millage from this calculation is that the coefficient for millage is 1. While the other coefficients are really small.

Also note you have enought coefficients since you add the bias column, so number of coeficients equals the features including bias column.

Since you don't show how you obtain you coefficients I can't tell you if anything has gone wrong there. (Setting the right dependent variable etc.)

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @KaranShishoo in the [comments above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78165544/internal-working-of-linear-regression-in-scikit-learn/78166223?noredirect=1#comment137803126_78165544), I was not dropping the price column before feeding the data to the Linear Regression Model which is why it was causing this ambiguity.